In the contex of Kernel regression why do we define the feature map as equal to the Kernel $\varphi(x)=k(\cdot ,x)$?
I have a notational confusion I am trying to clear up. In the context of Kernel regression the following relationship between the kernel and the feature map is defined:
Consider a positive-definite real-valued kernel $ k:{\mathcal {X}}\times {\mathcal {X}}\to \mathbb {R}  $ on a non-empty set $\mathcal {X}$ with a corresponding reproducing kernel Hilbert space $H_{k} $.
Define a mapping
${\begin{aligned}\varphi \colon {\mathcal {X}}&\to H_{k}\\\varphi (x)&=k(\cdot ,x)\end{aligned}}$
(so that $ \varphi (x)=k(\cdot ,x) $ is itself a map $ \mathcal {X}\to \mathbb{R}  $). Since $k$ is a reproducing kernel, then
$ \varphi (x)(x')=k(x',x)=\langle \varphi (x'),\varphi (x)\rangle ,$
where$ \langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle $ is the inner product on $ H_{k}$.
Now this is all well and good but when I look at an example I am not sure how $ \varphi (x)=k(\cdot ,x) $ . For instance take the polynomial kernel of degree 2:
$$
k(x, x') = (x \cdot x' + 1)^2,
$$
In this case the feature map is
$$
\varphi(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
x^2 \\
\sqrt{2} \cdot x \\
1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
In fact $\langle \varphi (x'),\varphi (x)\rangle = k(x, x')$.  But how is $ \varphi (x)=k(\cdot ,x) $ ?  How am I supposed to understand this notation in this context?

Hi: To me, your question is reasonable because I always wondered similarly. I hope someone else responds with an answer.

The $\varphi$ satisfy this equation by definition. How your example $\varphi$ (which you mention after 'In this case the feature map is') relates to all this remains unclear.

@picky_porpoise It's a common example of a feature map used as an example in university courses and lecture notes.

@Monolite Maybe, but some context seems to be missing. How $\varphi$ defines a mapping is not clear. There is only one variable. Maybe a link to these examples you mention would help.

@picky_porpoise See these lecture notes by MIT: https://web.mit.edu/modernml/course/lectures/MLClassLecture3.pdf   but perhaps it is just a mismatch of notation from the Wikipedia article on the representer theorem I linked and the common way I have seen a feature map used in courses and lecture notes.


In fact $\langle \varphi (x'),\varphi (x)\rangle = k(x, x')$. But how is $ \varphi (x)=k(\cdot ,x) $ ? How am I supposed to understand this notation in this context?

TL;DR: The notation $\varphi(x) = k(\cdot, x)$ means that the feature map $\varphi$ transforms $x$ into a function that measures similarities between $x$ and all other points in the input space via the kernel $k$. This allows $\varphi(x)$ to represent the similarity information encoded by $k$, ensuring that the inner product $\langle \varphi(x'), \varphi(x) \rangle$ in the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) reproduces the kernel value $k(x', x)$.

I agree that this notation can be confusing. I will try to clarify it:
Kernel Regression and Feature Mapping
1) Kernel Definition
A kernel $k(x, x')$ is a function that measures the similarity between two points $x$ and $x'$ in the input space $\mathcal{X}$. For a given kernel, there exists a corresponding Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) $H_k$.
2) Feature Mapping
The feature map $\varphi: \mathcal{X} \to H_k$ is defined such that for any $x \in \mathcal{X}$, $\varphi(x) = k(\cdot, x)$. Here, $\varphi(x)$ is an element of $H_k$, and $k(\cdot, x)$ represents a function in $H_k$ that takes any $x' \in \mathcal{X}$ and maps it to $k(x', x)$.
3) Reproducing Property
The RKHS has the reproducing property: for any $f \in H_k$ and any $x \in \mathcal{X}$, $f(x) = \langle f, k(\cdot, x) \rangle_{H_k}$. This property ensures that the inner product $\langle \varphi(x'), \varphi(x) \rangle_{H_k}$ in $H_k$ equals $k(x', x)$.
Example with Polynomial Kernel
For the polynomial kernel of degree 2:
$k(x, x') = (x \cdot x' + 1)^2$
We have the feature map:
$\varphi(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1^2 \\ x_2^2 \\ \sqrt{2} x_1 x_2 \\ \sqrt{2} x_1 \\ \sqrt{2} x_2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
We can dissect this as follows:
1) Constructing $\varphi(x)$:
The polynomial kernel can be expanded as:
$$
\begin{align}
k(x, x') &= (x \cdot x' + 1)^2 \\
         &= (x_1 x_1' + x_2 x_2' + 1)^2 \\
         &= x_1^2 x_1'^2 + 2 x_1 x_1' x_2 x_2' + x_2^2 x_2'^2 \\
         &\quad + 2 x_1 x_1' + 2 x_2 x_2' + 1
\end{align}
$$
The feature map $\varphi(x)$ is constructed to map $x$ into a higher-dimensional space such that:
$$\varphi(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1^2 \\ x_2^2 \\ \sqrt{2} x_1 x_2 \\ \sqrt{2} x_1 \\ \sqrt{2} x_2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
2) Reproducing the Kernel
The inner product in this higher-dimensional space is:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \varphi(x), \varphi(x') \rangle_{H_k} &= x_1^2 x_1'^2 + x_2^2 x_2'^2 + \sqrt{2} x_1 x_2 \sqrt{2} x_1' x_2' \\
&\quad + \sqrt{2} x_1 \sqrt{2} x_1' + \sqrt{2} x_2 \sqrt{2} x_2' + 1 \\
&= x_1^2 x_1'^2 + x_2^2 x_2'^2 + 2 x_1 x_2 x_1' x_2' \\
&\quad + 2 x_1 x_1' + 2 x_2 x_2' + 1
\end{align}
$$
This reproduces the polynomial kernel:
$$k(x, x') = (x_1 x_1' + x_2 x_2' + 1)^2$$
Understanding $\varphi(x) = k(\cdot, x)$
$k(\cdot, x)$ represents a function from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which for any $x' \in \mathcal{X}$ gives $k(x', x)$, the similarity between $x'$ and $x$. In the RKHS $H_k$, $\varphi(x)$ maps $x$ to this function $k(\cdot, x)$.
Essentially, $\varphi(x)$ encapsulates the similarity information represented by $k$, transforming $x$ into a point in $H_k$. This ensures that inner products in $H_k$ correspond to kernel values, as demonstrated by $\langle \varphi(x'), \varphi(x) \rangle = k(x', x)$. This mapping allows the use of linear methods in the high-dimensional feature space induced by the kernel.

Thanks Robert for the detailed explanation. I will print out and read carefully. It's much appreciated.

@mlofton You're very welcome, and I hope it helps you ! If it does then please consider giving it an upvote :)

Gotcha. I just did that.

Thank you. Much obliged :)

Thank you for your answer. I think for it to click completely I would need to understand how the feature map corresponding to the polynomial kernel you used in your example is an element of $H_k$? If I am not mistaken $H_k$ is the space of polynomials of degree 2 and $\varphi(x)$ is a vector,  $< a,  \varphi(x) >$ with $a = (1,1,1,1,1,1)$ (for example) is a polynomial, is this what is meant?

@Monolite Yes, that seems correct. The feature map $\varphi(x)$ is indeed an element of $H_k$, the space of polynomials of degree up to 2. When you represent $\varphi(x)$ as a vector, any function in $H_k$ can be written as an inner product $\langle a, \varphi(x) \rangle$, where $a$ is a vector of coefficients. For example, with $a = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$, the polynomial $\langle a, \varphi(x) \rangle$ matches the polynomial expansion in $H_k$, confirming that $\varphi(x)$ is a valid element of this space.

@RobertLong Sorry to be a bother but I was also wondering how do I compute the integral   to check for the reproducing property $f(x) = \langle f, k(\cdot, x) \rangle_{H_k} =  \int f(y) k(y, x) , dy$, for instance when $f(x) =1$ I don't seem to get $\int  k(y,x) , dy = 1$ .

@Monolite to compute the integral $\int k(y, x) , dy$ to check for the reproducing property $f(x) = \langle f, k(\cdot, x) \rangle_{H_k}$ for $f(x) = 1$, you set up the integral $\int (y \cdot x + 1)^2 , dy$ and compute each term's integral. Combining these results (I think) gives you:
$$
x^2 \left( \frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3} \right) + x (b^2 - a^2) + (b - a)
$$
The integral equals 1 when appropriate limits $a$ and $b$ are chosen, ensuring the reproducing property is satisfied.
Let me know if you need the intermediate steps :)

@RobertLong  This seems to imply that $b-a=1$ and that $b= -a$ since $b^2 -a^2 = (b+a)(b-a)$  but then, since $ b^3 - a^3 = (a-b)(  b^2 + ab + a^2 ) = a^2  $ we would need $a^2 = 0$ but that does not work. So I guess I might need some help with the intermediate steps :)

@Monolite Oh dear, hopefully I didn’t make a mistake there ! I’m on the road just now and can’t really look at it right now. Will def have another look as soon as I can though.

This is a response to the comment on my other answer, asking for the intermediate steps to compute the integral discussed:
To compute the integral to check for the reproducing property, we'll use the definition of the RKHS and the kernel function. We will work through the integral step by step, specifically when $f(x) = 1$.
Integral for Reproducing Property
The reproducing property states that:
$f(x) = \langle f, k(\cdot, x) \rangle_{H_k} = \int f(y) k(y, x) \, dy$
Given $f(x) = 1$, we want to verify:
$1 = \int k(y, x) \, dy$
We use the polynomial kernel of degree 2 as an example:
$k(x, y) = (x \cdot y + 1)^2$
Steps to Compute the Integral

Express the Kernel Function:
$k(x, y) = (x \cdot y + 1)^2$

Integral Setup:
$\int (y \cdot x + 1)^2 \, dy$

Expand the Kernel Function:
$(y \cdot x + 1)^2 = y^2 x^2 + 2 y \cdot x + 1$

Integrate Each Term:
Assuming we are integrating over a suitable range $[a, b]$:
$\int_a^b (y^2 x^2 + 2 y \cdot x + 1) \, dy$

Integrate $y^2 x^2$:
$x^2 \int_a^b y^2 \, dy = x^2 \left[ \frac{y^3}{3} \right]_a^b = x^2 \left( \frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3} \right)$

Integrate $2 y \cdot x$:
$2 x \int_a^b y \, dy = 2 x \left[ \frac{y^2}{2} \right]_a^b = 2 x \left( \frac{b^2}{2} - \frac{a^2}{2} \right) = x (b^2 - a^2)$

Integrate the constant term:
$\int_a^b 1 \, dy = [y]_a^b = b - a$




Combine the Results
Combine the results to get the integral:
$\int_a^b (y \cdot x + 1)^2 \, dy = x^2 \left( \frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3} \right) + x (b^2 - a^2) + (b - a)$
Verify the Reproducing Property
To verify the reproducing property, we need the integral to be equal to 1. This requires choosing the appropriate limits of integration $a$ and $b$ that satisfy:
$1 = x^2 \left( \frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3} \right) + x (b^2 - a^2) + (b - a)$
However, the result may depend on the specific kernel function and the domain of integration. For the polynomial kernel, the integral might not simplify directly to 1 without additional context or constraints on $a$ and $b$.
Conclusion
The integral can be computed as shown, and the result depends on the specific kernel function and integration limits. For $f(x) = 1$ and the polynomial kernel, additional context may be required to ensure the integral satisfies the reproducing property directly.

But how does one choose the appropriate limits of integration $a,b$   that satisfy: $1 = x^2 \left( \frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3} \right) + x (b^2 - a^2) + (b - a)$ ?  As per my comment above it does not seem possible to do so.
